# Does anyone know how to access the creation date of a user in Django's built in User library

Tags: django, module, attributes

I'd like to be able to use the date of when a user is created in Django's built in User module.

Is there a way to access this or will I have to add it in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`date_joined`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.date_joined) attribute.